# Google Recaptcha not working in iOS webview

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, recaptcha

I have a web page that I load in my iPhone app that has a form that sends me feedback. In case someone figures out the website url and accesses the page without using an iPhone, I want to ensure they're not a robot, as advised by my system admin.

When I setup the Google Recaptcha and view it in my iPhone app, the captcha renders in a separate Safari window not the app's webview.

I found this question without an answer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/webview/recaptcha/spLNfrT9nCM/t8aAuDzKBwAJ

My website with the form I want to add the Recaptcha to uses PHP.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to setup ReCaptcha in an app or in a web page?